# Euler's Rotation Theorem Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I want to prove Euler's rotation theorem:

> In three-dimensional space, any displacement of a rigid body such that a point on the rigid body remains fixed, is equivalent to a single rotation about some axis that runs through the fixed point.

I have just finished studying the matrix proof of Euler's rotation theorem as stated in the wikipedia page [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem)

The author just takes an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix $R$ and proves that $\lambda = 1$ is eigenvalue for this matrix. I do not understand why this proves that such rigid body displacement is rotation by some axis. For me it only shows rotation matrix properties.

Answer (score 1):

Some point is fixed, so take this as the origin. Write the rotation as $x\mapsto Rx$. Since $R$'s eigenvalues are $\pm1$, an arbitrary point is of the form $x_++x_-$ with $Rx_\pm=\pm x_\pm$. Then $Rx=x_+-x_-$, so $x$ is fixed iff $x_-=0$, i.e. iff $x$ is on the axis through $O$ parallel to an eigenvalue-$1$ vector.

Comment: How can you write every point uniquely in the form $p + v + w$, here you state that $p = Rp$ and $v= Rv$, ant $w$ is orthogonal to $v$, so you can not express every point in this way.

Comment: @giorgigona I never said $Rp=p$. I said the transformation is of the form $x\mapsto p+R(x-p)$, which has $p$ as a fixed point.

Comment: Than I do not understand why transformation is $x↦p+R(x−p)$ this form?

Comment: So my question from your answer is: If $R$ is the displacement matrix for which we should prove that it is a rotation matrix. So every $x↦Rx$. Than how can you say that $x↦p+R(x−p)$ if $Rp ≠ p$

Comment: @giorgigona Rotations *that fix the origin* are of the form $x\mapsto Rx$. Linear maps that fix a given point $p$ are of the form $x\mapsto p+A(x-p)$. If you translate the Cartesian axes so the point the OP posits to be fixed becomes $O$, you can set $p=O$  in everything I've done.

Comment: I do not understand why your statement is a proof of my question. Please can you write answer in more details?

Comment: @giorgigona See edit.

Comment: Yes i understand that from your proof if $R$ is the rotation matrix than clearly you can construct the rotation axis. But my question is why do we know that $R$ is a rotation matrix?

Comment: @giorgigona It's equivalent to lengths in the body being invariant under the linear transformation, i.e. to its being rigid.